# Pass Graphql input arguement to directive

Tags: graphql, gqlgen

I have a simple graphql query and a directive

```
directive @isOwner(postID: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

type Query {
  post(postID: String!): Post! @isOwner(postID: postID)
}
```

The problem is that I'm using [GQLGen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/master/docs/content/reference/directives.md) to generate my boilerplate code for Go, and directives are treated differently from the input values. 
This presents a unique challenge where authorization logic is almost isolated from the actual db reads, which makes the logic very inefficient, in that I have to eiither make a database read twice: during validation and the actual db read.
The data required for validation is also required for the db read, and I would have to edit my whole code to inject this data into context.
Is there a way of passing the input arguements dynamically to the directive and have the validation done dynamically and is it a good pracise in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments passed to schema directives are evaluated when your schema is initially built, so they can't be dynamic. In this particular case, you don't need an argument at all -- you can just read the value of the *field's* arguments.

```
visitFieldDefinition(field) {
  const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
  field.resolve = async function (parent, args, context, info) {
    console.log(args.postID)    

    return resolve.apply(this, [parent, args, context, info])
  }
}
```

However, if the name of the argument varies by field, then you can pass *that* as an argument to your directive

```
directive @isOwner(argName: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

```
visitFieldDefinition(field) {
  const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
  const { argName } = this.args
  field.resolve = async function (parent, args, context, info) {
    console.log(args[argName])    

    return resolve.apply(this, [parent, args, context, info])
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using GQLGen to generate my boilerplate code for Go, and directives are treated differently from the input values. 
I've also modified my question to further explain my dilemma

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, not sure if my case can be salvaged though